# jquery value calculation depending on drop down selection

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

This my code:

```
$('#paying_by').click(function()
{       
       if ($(this).val() == "GBPTRF")
       {
          $('.currency').html('&#163 ');
          $('#c_card_rate').val("0.00");
          $('#c_card_amount').val("0.00");
          $('.total_inc_charges').val(); /*???? refresh? this is the question*/
          $('.c_card_field').hide();            
       }                

       if ($(this).val() == "GBPCCARD")
       {
          $('.currency').html('&#163 ');
          $('.c_card_field').show();    
       }    

});
```

By default the c_card_field is hidden. If the user clicks on GBPCCARD then 2 fields appear within the c_card_field. One of them is the c_card_rate which is a %. Then the total amount increses with amount_due*c_card_rate/100. If the user selects GBPTRF again then, the c_card_field disappears.  Of course I clear the the c_card_rate field but the total amount which has been increased by the `c_card_amount(amount_due*c_card_rate/100)` remains increased until I amend the amoun_due field.

Question: 
How can I refresh the total_inc_charges when the user clicks GBPTRF again?

Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you recalculate the `total_inc_charges`?

Comment: I used jquery.calculation for the calculation.  It looks like this $(function() {
        $('input[name^=sum]').keyup(function() {
        var sum1 = parseFloat($('input[name=sum1]').val()) || 0;
  var sum2 = parseFloat($('input[name=sum2]').val()) || 0;
  var sum3 = parseFloat($('input[name=sum3]').val()) || 0;                  $('#total_inc_charges').val((sum1*sum3/100)+sum1);  });
    });                                               and I'm not really sure how to do it out of this function...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your last comment. I would refactor your code like this:

```
var calc_total_inc_charges = function () {
    var sum1 = parseFloat($('input[name=sum1]').val()) || 0;
    var sum2 = parseFloat($('input[name=sum2]').val()) || 0;
    var sum3 = parseFloat($('input[name=sum3]').val()) || 0;
    return (sum1*sum3/100)+sum1;
};

$(function() {
    $('input[name^=sum]').keyup(function() {
        $('#total_inc_charges').val(calc_total_inc_charges());
    });
});
```

Now you can call `calc_total_inc_charges()` whenever you like to recalculate charges.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Then I realized that without the credit card charges the actual total including charges is none of other than amount_due. so I did this: $('#total_inc_charges').val(($('#amount_due').val()));

Comment: I don't even know why I used jquery.calculation... Lot easier to work with .val(). Learning... :)